# get data from table having records in hindi

Tags: mysql

I have a table and in which column has data in Hindi and English. i want to fetch records which are in Hindi

```
+------+-------------------------------------+
| id   | urls                                |
+------+-------------------------------------+
| 1    | ICIBVC/05-अप्रैल-19/ICIBVC_95         |
| 2    | ICIBVC/06-Apr-19/ICIBVC_95          |
| 3    | ICIBVC/06-अप्रैल-19/ICIBVC_96         |
+------+-------------------------------------+
```

the output will be

```
+------+-------------------------------------+
| id   | urls                                |
+------+-------------------------------------+
| 1    | ICIBVC/05-अप्रैल-19/ICIBVC_95         |
| 3    | ICIBVC/06-अप्रैल-19/ICIBVC_96         |
+------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: In Hindi/Devanagari, are the months the same as in English/Europe?

Comment: Yea, months are same just translation is in Hindi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safe:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE urls RLIKE '[^ -~]'
```

Strong:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE urls RLIKE '[ऀ-ॿ]'
```

Comment: it works like a charms. Thanks

Comment: Coincidence.  `RLIKE` does not work with `UTF-8` characters until MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE urls REGEXP '^(..)*E0A[45]'
```

will test `urls` for containing Devanagari characters, which in utf8, are 3-byte characters, hex

```
E0A4xx
E0A5xx
```

This should work in any version of MySQL or MariaDB.